# Android: If you use an AlarmManager to wake up the phone, does the phone go to sleep as soon as your task completes?

Tags: android, sleep, alarm, alarmmanager, android-alarms

If the phone ***does*** fall asleep as soon as you are done keeping it up, that brings me to the second curiosity question:

How often can the phone wake up and fall asleep before it becomes inefficient? (more waste than staying on the whole time)